# Stubbing Redis interactions in javascript using Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, mocha.js, sinon

I am working in node.js.  My app interacts with Redis via the `node_redis` module. I'm using mocha and sinon to automate testing of my app.  My app looks something like this:

```
...snip
var redisClient = redis.createClient(redisPort, redisHost);
var someValue = redisClient.get("someKey");
return someValue;
....
```

I want to stub the call to redisClient.get().  To do this I also need to stub the call to redis.createClient() - I think...  Here's my test code:

```
...
var redis = require("redis");
var redisClient;
...
sinon.stub(redisClient, 'get').returns("someValue");
sinon.stub(redis, "createClient").returns(redisClient);
...
assert.equal(redis_client_underTest.call_to_redis(), "someValue");
...
```

The test fails with `AssertionError: false == "someValue"`

How do I stub out `redisClient`, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 12):

What you could do is use something like [Proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) or [Rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire). I'll be using rewire for the example.

Your snippet of code you want to stub:

```
var redisClient = redis.createClient(redisPort, redisHost);
var someValue = redisClient.get("someKey");
return someValue;
```

Then in your test you can use rewire:

```
var Rewire = require('rewire');

var myModule = Rewire("../your/module/to/test.js");

var redisMock = {
    get: sinon.spy(function(something){
             return "someValue";
         });
};

myModule.__set__('redisClient', redisMock);
```

This way you can have your redisClient replaced and you can check with the spy if the function was called.

Comment: Does the redisClient variable have to be exposed? Or can this rewire private variables in modules too?

Comment: @Scotty Yeah, it can rewire private variables too. :)

Comment: Game changer! Thanks so much! :D

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Thanks a lot @Osukaa.
Though faced one error. The semicolon get is not required. It gives kind of compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Few key points are:

- Stub redisClient before loading main module.
- Stub the CRUD methods for redisClient.

Below is my main module:

```
/* Main module */
const redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

function value(){
  return redisClient.get('someKey');
}

module.exports = {value: value}
```

Below is my test script:

```
/* Test */
var sinon = require('sinon');
var redis = require('redis');

// stub redis.createClient

var redisClient = {
    'get': () => "someValue"
}

var redisGetSpy = sinon.spy(redisClient, "get");
var redisClientStub = sinon.stub(redis,
                                 "createClient").callsFake(() => redisClient);

// require main module
var main = require('./main.js');

console.log(main.value(),
            redisClientStub.called,
            redisGetSpy.called, 
            redisGetSpy.callCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like [redis-mock](https://github.com/yeahoffline/redis-mock) which is a drop in replacement for `node_redis` that runs in memory.

Use `rewire` (or Jest module mocks or whatever) to load the mock client in your tests instead of the real client and run all your tests against the in-memory version.

Comment: IMO this is a much thorough testing solution because it tests actual app logic that is based on what redis is expected to return rather than simply checking that some stub function is called.  Plus you can rely on the tests within the mocked redis package to prove it is mocking correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to do in your class static function `getRedis` and mock it. For example:

```
let redis = {
   createClient: function() {},
};
let connection = {
   saddAsync: function() {},
   spopAsync: function() {},
};
let saddStub = sinon.stub(connection, 'saddAsync');
sinon.stub(redis, 'createClient').returns(connection);
sinon.stub(Redis, 'getRedis').returns(redis);

expect(saddStub).to.be.calledOnce;
```

Inside your class connect function looks like:

```
this.connection = YourClass.getRedis().createClient(port, host, optional);
```

Answer (score 0):

This initially seemed very trivial to me, but I was faced with a lot of caveats, particularly because I was using [jest](https://jestjs.io/) for testing, which does not supports  [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire). My objective was to mock the request dependency of [redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis), so here's how I achieved it:

```
// The objective is to mock this dependency
const redis = require('redis');

const redisClient = redis.createClient();
redis.set('key','value');
```

Mocking dependency with [rewiremock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewiremock):

```
const rewiremock = require('rewiremock/node');

const app = rewiremock.proxy('./app', {
  redis: {
    createClient() { 
      console.log('mocking createClient');
    },
    set() {
      console.log('mocking set');
    }
  },
});
```

The catch is that you can't use rewire, or `proxyquire` with `jest`, that you need a library like `rewiremock` to mock this dependency.

[REPL example](https://repl.it/@mkotsollaris/Mock-Redis)

Answer (score 0):

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const redis = require('redis');
const { mapValues, isObject, isUndefined, noop, isFunction } = require('lodash');

let redisStub;
let redisStore = {};

const removeKeyWhenExpired = (db, key, expirationSec) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        redisStore[db || 0][key] = undefined;
    }, expirationSec * 1000);
};

sinon.stub(redis, 'createClient').callsFake(() => ({
    on: () => { },
    select: (db) => {
        this.db = db;
        redisStore[db] = {};
    },
    get: (key, callback) => callback(null, redisStore[this.db || 0][key]),
    set: (key, value, ...args) => {
        redisStore[this.db || 0][key] = isObject(value) ? JSON.stringify(value) : value;
        if (args[0] === 'EX') {
            removeKeyWhenExpired(this.db, key, args[1]);
        }
        const callback = args[args.length - 1] || noop;
        if (isFunction(callback)) {
            callback(null, true);
        }
    },
    del: (key, callback = noop) => {
        if (!isUndefined(redisStore[this.db || 0][key])) {
            redisStore[this.db || 0][key] = undefined;
            return callback(null, 1);
        }
        return callback(null, 0);
    },
    expireat: (key, exp, callback = noop) => {
        removeKeyWhenExpired(this.db, key, exp - (new Date().getTime() / 1000));
        return callback(null);
    },
}));
```