# Mocking Redis Constructor with Sinon

Tags: javascript, testing, redis, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to figure out a way to mock redis in this module:

```
const Redis  = require('ioredis');
  const myFunction = {
    exists: (thingToCheck) {
      let redis_client = new Redis(
        6379,
        process.env.REDIS_URL,
        {
          connectTimeout: 75,
          dropBufferSupport: true,
          retryStrategy: functionHere
        });

    redis_client.exists(thingToCheck, function (err, resp) {
     // handlings in here
    });
  }
};
```

Using this test-code:

```
const LambdaTester = require('lambda-tester');
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const mockRedis = sinon.mock(require('ioredis'));

describe( 'A Redis Connection error', function() {
    before(() => {
        mockRedis.expects('constructor').returns({
            exists: (sha, callback) => {
                callback('error!', null);
            }
        });
      });

      it( 'It returns a database error', function() {
          return LambdaTester(lambdaToTest)
              .event(thingToCheck)
              .expectError((err) => {
                   expect(err.message).to.equal('Database error');
              });
      });
});
```

I also tried a few variations, but I'm kind of stuck as I basically need to mock the constructor and I'm not sure Sinon supports this?

```js
mockRedis.expects('exists').returns(
  (thing, callback) => {
    callback('error!', null);
  }
);
sinon.stub(mockRedis, 'constructor').callsFake(() => console.log('test!'));
sinon.stub(mockRedis, 'exists').callsFake(() => console.log('test!'));
```

Not sure what else to try here, I also tried using [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937212/stubbing-redis-interactions-in-javascript-using-sinon), but using `mockRedis.__set__("exists", myMock);` never set that private variable.

I want to fake my error paths ultimately.
I would love to hear what others are doing to test redis in node js .

Comment: Maybe you can have a look on unit test of ioredis, https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/master/test/helpers/mock_server.js , there is how ioredis build a fake server.

Comment: Cool thanks! I ended up just creating a local redis server with Docker and killing it for my error testing, but when I have more time I want to build a better mock.

Comment: But the above does work great, just would rather not have to have a docker dependency to run tests

Comment: Yes, Docker is really suitable for building testing database. In my case, I usually connect the app to redis cluster in docker, but I stub all redis operations. Thus the redis is always empty, but it saves lots of efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not whether Sinon supports this or that, but rather a missing understanding of how "classes" work in Ecmascript, as shown by the attempt at stubbing `constructor` property in the test code. That will never work, as that property has nothing to do with how any resulting objects turn out. It is simply a reference to the function that was used to create the object. I have covered [a very similar topic on the Sinon tracker](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-197608895) that you might have interest in reading to gain some core JS foo :-) Basically, it is not possible to stub a constructor, but you can probably coerce your code to use another constructor function in its place through either DI or link seams.

As a matter of fact, a few answers down in the same thread, you will see me covering an example of how I myself designed a Redis using class to be easily testable by supporting dependency injection. You might want [to check it out](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-198081263), as it is more or less directly applicable to your example module above.

Another technique, which you already has tried getting to work, is using *link seams* (using `rewire`). The Sinon homepage has a [nice article](http://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/) on doing this. Both `rewire` and `proxyquire` will do the job just fine here: I think you have just complicated the matter a bit by wrapping the require statement with a mock.

Even though I am on the Sinon maintainer team, I never use the `mock` functionality, so I cannot tell you how to use that, as I think it obscures the testing, but to get the basic link seams working using `rewire` I would basically remove all the Sinon code first and get the basic case going (removing `redis` for a stubbed module you have created).

Only then, add Sinon code as required.

Comment: This is super useful, thanks! Learned some new things today :D

Comment: Sweet, always nice if one can help out. Ping back if you should go ahead with this and get stuck. Might update with some details if needed.