# Integrating Jest and Rewire

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, jestjs

Working on getting a project transitioned over from Mocha to Jest to take advantage of the speed in running tests as well as the Jest framework itself and running into an issue. [Rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) is used pretty extensively in the codebase and I'm having an issue when running the gulp-jest task and *only* for those files that use rewire. I assume it has something to do with modules loading or not loading, but I'm stumped. Here's the really bare-bones gulp task, doesn't have much to it. I've already run through an extensive codemod on the codebase and many tests pass, just not those that use rewire.

```
gulp.task('jest', function() {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
    return gulp.src('name/path').pipe(
        jest({
            preprocessorIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
            automock: false,
            resetModules: true,
            setupFiles: ['./jestsetup.js']
        })
    );
});

gulp.task('newtest', function(callback) {
    runSequence('env', 'jest', callback);
});
```

Any time the rewire-related files are run, they complain about the file not being found. Am I missing anything here? I'm certain the modules themselves have the correct path set for the `require`.

Here's the actual error from jest/rewire:

```
 FAIL  path/to/folder/file/app.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '../../../../path/to/folder/file/app'

      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
      at internalRewire (node_modules/rewire/lib/rewire.js:23:25)
      at rewire (node_modules/rewire/lib/index.js:11:12)
      at Object.<anonymous (path/to/folder/file/app.test.js:10:14)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Using node 6.X, jest 20.x

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Jest has its own mechanism of mocking import, it's called [jest.mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html).

You will need to switch to using that instead of rewire.

Example

```
// banana.js
module.exports = () => 'banana';

// __tests__/test.js
jest.mock('../banana');

const banana = require('../banana'); // banana will be explicitly mocked.

banana(); // will return 'undefined' because the function is auto-mocked.
```

example was taken from [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)

Comment: Right, I understand that, but is there any way around it? We use rewire really heavily and it's non-trivial to have to re-write using jest's mocking tools. Wonder if I could dynamically dontMock things and bypass Jest?

Comment: *I believe it's `unmock` now

Comment: Maybe you can monkey patch `rewire`, write your own "rewire" function that in the internals it will use jest.mock.

Put it on the jest.setup file https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string

Comment: Interesting, seems like something like that could work. Was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to something like this but it'd be less work than rewriting a 1,000 tests :)

Comment: Second option is to use codemod, something like that https://github.com/skovhus/jest-codemods, or write one :] take an inspiration from https://github.com/skovhus/jest-codemods/blob/master/src/utils/proxyquire.js

Comment: Could work! The only thing I could see being a problem is that our usage of rewire isn't just syntactic, it also has an aspect that might be tough with a codemod. Tests are littered w/ module reversions that would all need manual cleanup :/

Answer (score -1):

To my surpise, Proxyquire was not compatible with jest. To mock a dependency you would need to utilize a mocking library, like [rewiremock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewiremock).

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58034943/1373465) and this [REPL example](https://repl.it/@mkotsollaris/Mock-Redis) on how to successfully mock dependent packages.