# How to mock module function using proxyquire

Tags: node.js, sinon, stub, sinon-chai, proxyquire

I need to mock 'mkdirp-promise' node module which exposes a constructor function as below

```
mkdirpPromise(dirPath)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('ABCDEFGH');
            resolve(dirPath);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('HeABCDEFGHre');
            const details = error.message;
            const err = customError.failed_create_downloads_directory()
                .withDetails(details);
            reject(err);
        });
```

Im able to mock it using proxiquire as below for the first time:-

```
let mkdirpPromiseMock = sinon.stub().rejects();

 const sthreeDownloadMock =
    proxyquire('./../../modules/sThreeDownload', {
        joi: joiMock,
        fs: fsMock,
        '@monotype/core-error': {
            errors: {
                ApiError: customErrorMock,
            },
        },
        'aws-sdk': awsSDK,
        'mkdirp-promise': mkdirpPromiseMock,
        path: pathMock,
    });
```

Now i want to override mkdirpPromiseMock in 2nd test case with

```
mkdirpPromiseMock = sinon.stub().resolves();
```

which im not able to. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That should have worked fine, but "which im not able to" is not really providing any details with which we could help you. A simplified case that is runnable and shows the problem would help

Answer (score 0):

`Proxyquire` is not compatible with `jest`.

You need to use a mocking library like [rewiremock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewiremock).

Please have a [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937212/stubbing-redis-interactions-in-javascript-using-sinon/58034943#58034943) which goes into detail.

[REPL example](https://repl.it/@mkotsollaris/Mock-Redis)